Comparing moving averages actual position on chart and changing color based on the outcome
I have issues with my part of code that is trying to compare smma2 position to dema1 position on chart.
What I want is:

if dema1 is green and smma2 is above dema1 then smma2_color should be blue
if dema1 is green but smma2 is below dema1 then smma2_color should be orange
if dema1 is red and smma2 is below dema1 then smma2_color should be blue
if dema1 is red but smma2 is above dema1 then smma2_color should be orange

What I have so far, ta.change compares values instead of position (my guess?) so the result is incorrect and I cant figure out what to swap it with:
// DEMA COLOR CHANGE
dema1color = ta.change(dema1)>=0 ? color.green : color.red
dema1ColorFlip = dema1color != nz(dema1color[1])
barcolor(dema1ColorFlip ? dema1color : na) 
t1 = plot(dema1, color=dema1color, linewidth=3, title="DEMA 1")

// Set SMMA 2 color based on DEMA 1 color and position
var color smma2_color = na
if (dema1color == color.green) and (ta.change(smma2) > 0)
    smma2_color := color.rgb(108, 214, 230, 50) // Blue
else if (dema1color == color.green) and (ta.change(smma2) <= 0)
    smma2_color := color.rgb(230, 183, 108, 50) // Orange
else if (dema1color == color.red) and (ta.change(smma2) > 0)
    smma2_color := color.rgb(230, 183, 108, 50) // Orange
else if (dema1color == color.red) and (ta.change(smma2) <= 0)
    smma2_color := color.rgb(108, 214, 230, 50) // Blue

Edit: this seems to do what I wanted but if someone could confirm that's a good solution it would be great!
var color smma2_color = na

if (dema1color == color.green)
    smma2_color := smma2 > dema1 ? color.rgb(108, 214, 230, 50) : (smma2 < dema1 ? color.rgb(230, 183, 108, 50) : na)

if (dema1color == color.red)
    smma2_color := smma2 < dema1 ? color.rgb(108, 214, 230, 50) : (smma2 > dema1 ? color.rgb(230, 183, 108, 50) : na)

